# Применение strpos

Tags: javascript

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined 
Кричит, что не может прочитать свойство:

> ```
> function check_digit(name,frac) {
>     if (isNaN(frac)) frac = 0;
>     if (frac <= 0) frac = -1;
>     var s = $(name).val();
>     alert(s);
>     var i = strpos(s.replace(',','.'),'.');
>     if (i !== false && i >= 0 && i < s.length-frac-1) {
>         $(name).val(s.substring(0,i+frac+1));
>     }
> }
> ```

Тут кричит, что не объявлена переменная add_summ, хотя она, как все, объявляется здесь:

```
s += '<td class="givc_in2 givc_brd_urdl" align="center"><input id="counter'+i+'_curr" class="inputbox not_border_input givc_txt" size="6" value="" onInput="recalc_counters('+i+',\'curr\')" onPropertyChange="recalc_counters('+i+',\'curr\')" onKeyUp="recalc_counters('+i+',\'curr\')" onCut="recalc_counters('+i+',\'curr\')" onPaste="recalc_counters('+i+',\'curr\')"></td>';
                s += '<td class="givc_in2 givc_brd_urd_" align="center"><input id="counter'+i+'_prev" class="inputbox not_border_input givc_txt" size="6" value="" onInput="recalc_counters('+i+',\'prev\')" onPropertyChange="recalc_counters('+i+',\'prev\')" onKeyUp="recalc_counters('+i+',\'prev\')" onCut="recalc_counters('+i+',\'prev\')" onPaste="recalc_counters('+i+',\'prev\')"></td>';
                s += '<td class="givc_in2 givc_brd_urd_" align="center"><input id="counter'+i+'_diff" class="inputbox not_border_input givc_txt" size="6" value="" onInput="recalc_counters('+i+',\'diff\')" onPropertyChange="recalc_counters('+i+',\'diff\')" onKeyUp="recalc_counters('+i+',\'diff\')" onCut="recalc_counters('+i+',\'diff\')" onPaste="recalc_counters('+i+',\'diff\')"></td>';
                s += '<td class="givc_in2 givc_brd_u_d_" align="center" style="background-color:#ebebeb;"><input id="counter'+i+'_trff" class="inputbox not_border_input givc_txt" size="6" style="background-color:#ebebeb;" value='+counter_tariff[i]+' readonly></td>';
                s += '<td class="givc_in2 givc_brd_urdl" align="center"><input id="counter'+i+'_summ" class="inputbox not_border_input givc_txt" size="8" value="" onInput="recalc_counters('+i+',\'summ\')" onPropertyChange="recalc_counters('+i+',\'summ\')" onKeyUp="recalc_counters('+i+',\'summ\')" onCut="recalc_counters('+i+',\'summ\')" onPaste="recalc_counters('+i+',\'summ\')" style="font-weight:bold;"></td>';
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему с невозможностью прочесть свойство?

**Обновление**

strpos:

```
function strpos( haystack, needle, offset){ 
var i = haystack.indexOf( needle, offset );
return i >= 0 ? i : false;
}
```

Comment: alert(s); что показывает?

Comment: И да, что это за strpos? В js нет такой функции.

Comment: alert = undefined

Comment: И как вы думаете, почему? И измените заголовок вопроса, он не соответствует содержанию.

Comment: Если б я знал почему, не обращался за помощью. Вы спрашивали про strpos? Обновил ответ

Comment: @AndyLarkin, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, что содержится в переменной `name` на момент вызова функции `check_digit`. Для этого поставьте в самом начале вызова функции check_digit ключевое слово

```
debugger;
```

Затем откройте консоль Firebug (или аналогичную консоль Google Chrome), вкладка "Сценарий". Перезагрузите страницу и создайте ситуацию, при которой происходит вызов функции `check_digit`. Произойдет остановка сценария в том месте, где объявлен `debugger`. Теперь наведите мышкой на переменную `name` и во всплывающей подсказке должно появится значение, хранящееся в ней, - это должен быть правильный селектор jQuery. Убедитесь в том, что элемент, соответствующий селектору, присутствует на момент вызова функции `check_digit`. Если нет, то измените селектор так, чтобы выражение

```
$(name).val();
```

возвращало значение, отличающееся от `undefined`.

**Обновление**

Открываем консоль и вводим `$('#service0_add_summ').length;`, если консоль вернет 0, значит такого элемента на странице нет. `length` указывает на количество элементов с таким id на странице.

Comment: Открываем консоль и вводим $('#service0_add_summ').length; если консоль вернет 0, значит такого элемента на странице нет. length указывает на количество элементов с таким id на странице.

Comment: Смотрите, если его нет, как оно нам заталкивает его в селектор ?
и как возможно это поправить ?

Comment: То, что я описал в ответе, это пошаговая инструкция для дебаггинга JavaScript кода, но при этом нужно еще самому немного думать головой. Если у Вас не хватает для этого знаний, может, проще пригласить того, кто знает?